# Date validation pattern not working with Angular 2 Validation Pattern

Tags: regex, angular, validation, angular-material

I'm asking here as I suspect there is something with Angular 2 validation patterns that might be different than validation patterns in other languages.

I have a date pattern I used for my asp.net validation to get mm/dd/yyyy, that takes into account leap years etc, and also accepts m/d/yyyy.  It is being used as follows.

```
dateSubmitted: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('((^(10|12|0?[13578])([/])(3[01]|[12][0-9]|0?[1-9])([/])((1[8-9]\d{2})|([2-9]\d{3}))$)|(^(11|0?[469])([/])(30|[12][0-9]|0?[1-9])([/])((1[8-9]\d{2})|([2-9]\d{3}))$)|(^(0?2)([/])(2[0-8]|1[0-9]|0?[1-9])([/])((1[8-9]\d{2})|([2-9]\d{3}))$)|(^(0?2)([/])(29)([/])([2468][048]00)$)|(^(0?2)([/])(29)([/])([3579][26]00)$)|(^(0?2)([/])(29)([/])([1][89][0][48])$)|(^(0?2)([/])(29)([/])([2-9][0-9][0][48])$)|(^(0?2)([/])(29)([/])([1][89][2468][048])$)|(^(0?2)([/])(29)([/])([2-9][0-9][2468][048])$)|(^(0?2)([/])(29)([/])([1][89][13579][26])$)|(^(0?2)([/])(29)([/])([2-9][0-9][13579][26])$))')]],
```

This pattern worked perfectly in my asp.net app but it is not in Angular2, it fails whether I try and type the correct date format into the input box or use the material date picker to enter it.  I haven't been able to find anything regarding this.  I have been successful applying other patterns in Angular2, like email.

My angular versions in my package.json are as follows, if this info is needed:

```
"@angular/animations": "^4.3.6",
    "@angular/cdk": "^2.0.0-beta.10",
    "@angular/common": "^4.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.1.0",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.1.0",
    "@ngrx/core": "^1.2.0",
```

Edit: added plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/qHPZceVTpS4x1AEqZfjA

Comment: Double all ``\`` in the pattern.

Comment: That didn't quite work, are there other characters I have to escape as well?

Comment: Try copy/pasting the one [from here](https://regex101.com/r/RUPheX/1) (I double escaped `\d` there, the fiddle is not working).

Comment: I tested 9/21/2017 and 09/21/2017, both at that site and on my app, neither worked.

Comment: I'll have to check and see what else might be happening, it works in asp.net

Comment: BTW, [here is the demo](https://regex101.com/r/RUPheX/2) as if you put the regex I shared earlier into Angular code. Please share a fiddle to show you it is working. I am still sure my first comment is the solution.

Comment: Thank you for all of your help so far.  I'm done for the day but I'll be continuing on this tomorrow.  I'll be letting you know if you lead me to the solution, at which point I'll get you to put it in an answer.

Comment: Ok I finally figured out where I was having trouble with your link, it defaults to php.  I switched it to javascript and escaped all of the slashes to get the patterns matching with the sample dates on the regex tester, but something goes wrong when I copy it and paste it into the pattern string in the angular Validators.pattern('copied regex').  It still won't match in my application for some reason.

Comment: Please use https://plnkr.co/ to share a fiddle to repro the issue.

Comment: Bear with me while I figure this out, never been to plnkr before.

Comment: Note that you do not need to use `\/` in the `Validators` pattern, as it uses a constructor notation. The `/` is not a special char in regex.

Comment: Hmm, it prompted me to do that for the JavaScript version of the regex, but I suppose that because the pattern is a string in angular that escaping that isn't necessary.

Comment: Any news on this issue?

Comment: My apologies, I got tasked with something else and this fell off the backburner, I'm really sorry. I spent a few minutes on plunkr, I'm not sure how much of the project I need to put up to demonstrate my issue but I'll be able to spend more time on it in an hour or so.  Thank you so much for following up.

Comment: I believe I extracted enough to isolate the date field and validator.  Tell me if this plunker gives you what is needed. https://plnkr.co/edit/qHPZceVTpS4x1AEqZfjA

Comment: Ok doubling the '/' as per your initial suggestion works on the plunker, but still not my fuller app.  So I have some investigating to do.  In the interim, post that as an answer and I'll accept it as that was what was wrong with my regex.

Comment: Ok, posted. I think the issue might be with some ``\`` that was not escaped correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern you have been using is not compiled correctly due to `\d` being treated as a string escape sequence rather than a regex escape sequence. To achieve that, you need to double the backslashes.

Besides, your alternatives are all enclosed with `^` and `$` anchors. While it is correct, it does not look quite efficient: it makes sense to put one `^` at the beginning, and one `$` at the end of the pattern, while wrapping the alternatives within a non-capturing group.

Also, you may convert all your capturing groups to non-capturing ones (i.e. `(...)` to `(?:...)`) to gain some more performance, and replace `[/]` with a mere `/` since the `/` symbol does not need escaping inside `RegExp` constructor.

So, you may use

```
dateSubmitted: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^(?:(?:10|12|0?[13578])/(?:3[01]|[12][0-9]|0?[1-9])/(?:1[8-9]\\d{2}|[2-9]\\d{3})|(?:11|0?[469])/(?:30|[12][0-9]|0?[1-9])/(?:1[8-9]\\d{2}|[2-9]\\d{3})|0?2/(?:2[0-8]|1[0-9]|0?[1-9])/(?:1[8-9]\\d{2}|[2-9]\\d{3})|0?2/29/[2468][048]00|0?2/29/[3579][26]00|0?2/29/[1][89][0][48]|0?2/29/[2-9][0-9][0][48]|0?2/29/1[89][2468][048]|0?2/29/[2-9][0-9][2468][048]|0?2/29/1[89][13579][26]|0?2/29/[2-9][0-9][13579][26])$')]],
```

See the [updated Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/QUL7b5JLTgYEkXZVsfEk?p=preview).

Comment: Thank you for all of your time and patience with my issue.  I genuinely appreciate it.

Comment: I forgot to remove unnecessary non-capturing groups, done it now.

Comment: You are a regex ninja.